# AppAttest -- Can a Swift program that uses DCAppAttestService be run on Linux?

Tags: swift, macos, certificate, attestations, remote-attestation

I need to be able to run the code that issues an Apple **attest** but preferably Linux. Or, at the very least, on an MacOS **VPS**.

I expect there to be new customers daily, therefore this code will be run regularly, for each new client. As such, using an Apple **physical device** for this, if indeed required, will inconvenient:

```
import DCAppAttest

func generateKeyAndAttestation() {
    guard let attestationKey = DCAppAttestService.shared.generateKey() else {
        print("Error generating attestation key.")
        return
    }

    // Generate a nonce (you may need to use a more secure source for your actual use case)
    let nonce = Data.random(count: 32)

    // Prepare the data to be attested
    let dataToAttest = "Data to be attested".data(using: .utf8)!

    // Concatenate nonce and data
    var attestationData = nonce
    attestationData.append(dataToAttest)

    // Use DCAppAttestService to attest the data
    guard let attestation = DCAppAttestService.shared.attestData(attestationData, withKey: attestationKey) else {
        print("Error generating attestation.")
        return
    }

    // Print or use the attestation key and the resulting attestation
    print("Attestation Key: \(attestationKey)")
    print("Attestation: \(attestation)")
}
```

I haven't found a clear answer as to whether or not `DCAppAttestService` can be run **only on** MacOS/iOS or any other Apple OS?

And whether or not it has to be a **physical** Apple device or will any VPS running one of the latest OSX do too?

[image]

I'm aware that validation, verification of **attest-s** can, indeed, be run on Linux. This will the 2nd step. My question, however, about the code that issues, generates **attest-s** initially -- the 1st step.

---

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice

Comment: Since that API call accesses the Secure Enclave on Apple hardware, I’m presuming you may be in for a lot of work to emulate that on Linux, but let’s get this over to a peer site that is developer centric for a better read on the issue…